# Live streaming with red5 server not working on my live site

Tags: java, php, red5

I want to use live streaming on my website so I configured red5 on remote server and using it with my site. The streaming works properly on my localhost but not on my live site. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code snippet here, where you think something is wrong

Comment: I dont know what part of code is giving error. It is working properly when I use the ip adress and port of red5 server on local host but when I use the same details on live site I get this error -  

[ WARN] 9/10/15 4:57:37 PM [Logger] Method invocation failure onBWCheck, [{timePassed=0, payload=, latency=0, count=0, cumLatency=1, sent=0}] 

Is it related to java on my server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your remote server has the proper ports open and bound to support streaming from red5. Normally these are ports:

- 5080
- 1935